# Ordering depended tasks for a gradle task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle task which has dependencies on the subproject task. For example.

```
task bigTask(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: [":module1:task",
                                                ":module2:task",
                                                ":module3:task",
                                                ":module4:task",
                                                ":module5:task"]) { 
....
.....
}
```

I want to order the depended tasks in a specific way. So that at a time only one task get exeuted. I did like this in the root project. But it is not working.

```
task (":module1:task") { mustRunAfter (":module2:task") }
task (":module2:task") { mustRunAfter (":module3:task") }
task (":module3:task") { mustRunAfter (":module4:task") }
task (":module4:task") { mustRunAfter (":module5:task") }
```

Is there some way to order the dependent task in gradle.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the behaviour you want to model? There may be better ways to model it than the one you propose.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook I want to make sure that only one of the subtasks `(dependsOn)`execute at a time and should run in a sequence, meaning one after the another.

Comment: That just describes how you're tackling the problem, not what the problem you're trying to solve is. What are these sub tasks? Why do they need to run in a specific order? Why don't they depend on one another? Why are they in different projects?